# Chaining overloaded operators with different parameter types

Tags: c++11, overloading, operator-keyword, initializer-list, chaining

Let's say I have a class "Vector" (Math not Container) and I'd like to overload the operators, so I can chain calculations.

That works fine for me:

```
friend Vector operator+(const Vector<N, Type>& a, const Vector<N, Type>& b)
friend Vector operator+(      Vector<N, Type>& a, const Vector<N, Type>& b)
```

and with that I can do stuff like

```
auto a = vec<3>(.0f, .0f, .0f);
auto b = a + a + a;
```

However I also implemented an initializer list

```
Vector& operator=(Type const (&arr)[N])
```

Which makes it possible for me to write something like this:

```
a = { .1f, .1f, .1f };
a += { .1f, .1f, .1f };
```

However what I can't do is chain those initializer lists.

```
a = { .1f, .1f, .1f } + b;
a = { .1f, .1f, .1f } + { .1f, .1f, .1f };
```

I already tried adding operator overloads like

```
friend Vector operator+(const Vector<N, Type>& a, Type const (&arr)[N])     
friend Vector operator+(      Vector<N, Type>& a, Type const (&arr)[N])     
friend Vector operator+(Type const (&arr)[N], const Vector<N, Type>& a)     
friend Vector operator+(Type const (&arr)[N],       Vector<N, Type>& a)
```

but it doesn't work...

Is this possible?

Comment: Try to make a CONSTRUCTOR using an `std::initializer_list`, not an `operator =`

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible (not with this usage).

The expression `{ .1f, .1f, .1f } + { .1f, .1f, .1f };` is not a `Vector` and any overloading you define for `Vector` can't affect it.

My best suggestion is to add a zero term which is a vector:

`Vector zero_vec = { 0, 0, 0 };
a = zero_vec + { .1f, .1f, .1f } + { .1f, .1f, .1f };`

It relies on the fact that `operator+` is left-associative.